# Scrapy. I haven't result

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a work program. But my file json is empty.
My program should get all the articles with New York times.

```
class ParseSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "new"
    allowed_domains = ["www.nytimes.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.nytimes.com/section/world?WT.nav=page&action=click&contentCollection=World&module=HPMiniNav&pgtype=Homepage&region=TopBar"]

    rules = (
             Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//*[@id="story"]/div[3]/div[1]',)), callback="parse_items", follow= True),
             )

def parse_item(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    l = parseLoader(parse_item(), hxs)

    l.add_value('url', response.url)
    l.add_xpath('name', '//*[@id="headline"]' % u"Название статьи:")
    l.add_xpath('text', '//*[@id="story"]/div[3]/div[1]' % u"Текст:")
```

I am change program. Edit:

```
    rules = (
             Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//*[contains(@id,"story")]')), callback = 'parse_item'),
             )

def parse_item(self, response):
    l = parseLoader(response=response)

    l.add_value('url', response.url)
    l.add_xpath('name', '//*[@id="headline"]' % u"Название статьи:")
    l.add_xpath('text', '//*[@id="story"]/div[3]/div[1]' % u"Текст:")
    yield l.load_item()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you infinite recursion going on in your `parse_item` method.
You don't need to selector and `HtmlXpathSelector` shouldn't even be used. Try:

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    l = parseLoader(response=response)

    l.add_value('url', response.url)
    l.add_xpath('name', '//*[@id="headline"]' % u"Название статьи:")
    l.add_xpath('text', '//*[@id="story"]/div[3]/div[1]' % u"Текст:")
    yield l.load_item()
```

Edit: Seems like your linkextractor rule is not extracting anything.
First of all you shouldn't use `SgmlLinkExtractor` it's deprecated. Secondly your xpath doesn't capture anything, the xpath your are using is too specific and incorrect in some cases. Try:

```
LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//*[contains(@id,"story")]',))
```

You can debug and try this in `scrapy shell` command:

```
$ scrapy shell "https://www.nytimes.com/section/..."
from scrapy.linkextractor import LinkExtractor    
le = LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//*[contains(@id,"story")]',))
le.extract_links(response)
# 20 results will be printed
```

Comment: It didn't help me(

Comment: @Maria what's the error? could you post the output log? try running `scrapy crawl myspider -s LOG_FILE=/some/directory/myspider.log` and share with us what's in this log.

Comment: I can't do it. Because: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/some/directory/new.log'

Comment: @Maria that was an example -.- Are you running unix? If you do just run `scrapy crawl new &> output.log` and then upload the contents of output.log to some online pastebin and give us a link.

Comment: @Maria perfect! Seems like your LinkExtractor rule is not extracting anything, see my answer edit for more information.

Comment: Sorry for me( I change program(you can see in quation), in log write results good. But when i open csv file, he is empty.